# Pdf Generation using Rotativa in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf-generation, rotativa

I am Generating PDF using `Rotativa`. Below is my Function to generate PDF:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
{
    return new ViewAsPdf("pdfView")
    {
        FileName = "Fee_Challan.pdf",
        PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        PageSize = Size.A4,
        PageMargins = { Left = 10, Right = 10, Top = 15, Bottom = 22 },
        MinimumFontSize = 7,
        PageHeight = 40
    };
}
```

I'm Calling this function from `Create` method. When I call it in `return RedirectToAction("GeneratePDF");` it works fine.

But when I call it before the `return` statement, it does not work.

```
GeneratePDF(); //this does not work. But I want to use this approach.
return RedirectToAction("index","Applicants");
```

I want to load another view after PDF is generated, that is why I don't want to call `GeneratePDF()` in `RedirectToAction()`. The debugger shows that the method is being executed fine. Tell my why it is not Working.

Comment: Any body reply?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the PDF. Perhaps sending the PDF to the user and redirect to another page at the same time?

Comment: @GiorgioBozio yes. when User Clicks the Button, i want to generate PDF and then send it to user to Download  as well as redirect to another page so that user does not click **Generate PDF** button again and again.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the pdf process. Just use some javascript to manage user navigation.

Comment: But why calling **GeneratePDF()** works only in **RedirectToAction()** function.. And calling it as separate statement doesnot work?

Comment: Because it returns an ActionResult and you don't return it from your method. Asp.net mvc doesn't work te way you think.

Comment: What should i do to make it work without putting it in RedirectToAction()?

Comment: Perhaps you could redirect the user to the other page and have some javascript get the PDF via Ajax call to a method on server that uses BuildPdf method.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not working* because in your case the `GeneratePDF()` method indeed returns a view as pdf. So what are you doing with it? The answer is: Nothing!

```
GeneratePDF(); //this returns an ActionResult which contains your pdf, but you do nothing with it here
return RedirectToAction("index","Applicants"); // this redirects the user to another action
```

So in this case you can only redirect the user to another action or return the pdf. You can not have two return statements in the same method.

In order to make the user not being able to generate the same pdf again (which should be harmless, so which would be the problem if the user wants the pdf again? but it's your choice how you want your application to work) you will have to disable (hide or even redirect to another page, etc.) using javascript.

Hope this covers it all. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer(though its too late) i redirected to another view with success message and GENERATE pdf button there ... It solved my issue with form fields visible even after pdf is generated...